# phpmyadmin import CSV currency with comma's

Tags: import, phpmyadmin

I want to import my bankaccount CSV file with phpmyadmin into a dbase but in holland we use currency with the comma seperated the digits.

Whe i import this file the number collumn is not imported correct.
This is because mysql database uses dotś as separator.

Is there a way to correct that without changing it before uploading?

Or do i have to edit the file each time before i upload the file?

any help is welcome